# ZOHO JS SDK library code is not working on my VSCODE i want to make widget

Tags: javascript, sdk, widget, crm, zoho

I want to  build and package widgets in Zoho CRM. but i cant be able to use a single piece of code .I got error every time when i run code on ZOHO CRM. i got alway undefined value error in my code .I  try very thing but it not working .

I just try all thinks to explain in this documentation [ZOHO DOCUMENTATION](https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/widgets/create-widget.html)   But it is not working properly

I want to try to make widget in my ZOHO account but ZOHO sdk CDN is not working properly . could you please explain how can i use this CDN properly on code .I just want to make a widget

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src=" https://js.zohostatic.com/creator/widgets/version/1.0/widgetsdk-min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src=""></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>This is a sample Widget built using Zoho Extension toolkit.</h2>
    <h2>simple text</h2>
    <script>
      ZOHO.embeddedApp.on("PageLoad",function(data){ 
        console.log(data);
        ZOHO.CRM.CONFIG.getCurrentUser().then(function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                        });
      
      })
      ZOHO.embeddedApp.init()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are importing the wrong cdn for the SDK, replace this:

```
<script src=" https://js.zohostatic.com/creator/widgets/version/1.0/widgetsdk-min.js"></script>
```

with this:

```
<script src="https://live.zwidgets.com/js-sdk/1.2/ZohoEmbededAppSDK.min.js"></script>
```